# Is one to one mapping necessary between Write Applications and Read Applications

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, cqrs, event-sourcing, messaging

**Introduction:** We have a bunch of micro services (about 40) to serve our customers.

To facilitate scaling and audit-ability of selected few micro services we have decided to redesign them using CQRS and event sourcing.

**Current Situation:** We started out with a one to one mapping between read applications and write applications. For example WriteApplicationA and ReadApplicationA, WriteApplicationB and ReadApplicationB, so on...

**Problem:** However at this point, we are considering to have some read applications that listened to events from more than one write application.

Is it okay to have read applications that listen to events from more that one write application? (At this point it looks very convincing, but will I run in to errors in the future). (Reporting is the use case where we want to listen to events from multiple write applications)

Comment: Additional info: I am not looking at replacing all my read applications with a single one. I am looking at augmenting a reporting read application that listens to events from many write application

Comment: "Is it okay to have read applications that listen to events from more that one write application?" Yes.

Comment: Oh okay... Would that a separate bounded context. And will it have 2 or more anti corruption layers